# Error CS0103: The name 'Class1' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

In my website I created a class e.g. `Class1.cs` in App_Code folder when I am trying to load default page which is using this Class file I am getting the following error

`CS0103: The name 'Class1' does not exist in the current context` for the code

String something = Class1.item1(text1.Text, text2.Text);

and `Class1.cs` consists of

```
public static string item1(string a, string b)
{
//some action here
return null;
}
```

Everything works fine in my VS2010 but when I host the website in my server I am getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

check whether your site has permission to read or access App_Code folder. There might be a problem with u r server

Comment: go to  cpanel of your website or ask your hoster to checker.